# HTML Background image messed up with content on top

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm using this background image to stay in line with a brand package for a site and I have set it the following way:

```
html { 
    background: url(../img/GreyWeavePaper-Portrait.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But when I add an image via html (which is in .png format and is transparent on the background)  a big white strip comes with it. To combat this I set the body a back ground in CSS the following way:

```
body {
    background: url(../img/GreyWeavePaper-Portrait.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    margin-top: 80px;
    font-family: 'passport', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}
```

This is the result:
[image]

As you can see at the top of the image is the background set with html and where the logo is, is where the background is set with the body. could someone please help me get this background set like it is in the top of this image when I have content ontop of it?

Image  Dimensions are 300x150

```
@import url(../fonts/VINCHAND.ttf);
@import url(../fonts/Passport.ttf);

/*!
Main Page CSS || Created By Thomas Withers @ Ice7Media
 */

/* Global Styles
============================================================ */
html { 
  background: url(../img/GreyWeavePaper-Portrait.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    background: url(../img/GreyWeavePaper-Portrait.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    font-family: 'passport', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
    font-family: 'passport', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

p {
    font-family: 'passport', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

#topnavbar {
    margin: 0;
}
#topnavbar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.banner {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.banner img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<!-- Meta charset 
===================================================================================-->
        <meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Title  
===================================================================================-->
        <title>Bocaditio | South Amercian Dishes</title>

<!-- Meta Tags  
===================================================================================-->
        <meta name="author" content="Thomas Withers @ Ice7Media">
        <meta name="description" content="Social Media Wizzards that handle all of your social media markerting.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

        <!-- CSS Stylesheets  
===================================================================================-->
        <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/new_Custom.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/Mapstyle.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/iceBox.png">

<!-- Custom Fonts 
===================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

<!-- Logo Section 
===================================================================================-->
    <section class="banner" id="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <img src="img/BocaditoLogo_113x300.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

<!-- Navigation
===================================================================================-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" id="MainNav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">          
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- container-fluid -->
    </nav>
<!-- Full screen Slider    
===================================================================================--> 
<!-- Welcome Message
===================================================================================--> 
<!-- Latest Blog Post
===================================================================================-->
<!-- Three Images
===================================================================================-->
<!-- Map & Conatct
===================================================================================-->
<!-- Footer
===================================================================================-->
<!-- Scripts
===================================================================================-->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC22aNgIjcYzx5Oel1m0Jtcem-W4R895fQ"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fix-nav.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why does the body have a `margin-top`

Comment: @Paulie_D Just added that so you could see the difference removing has no effect

Comment: At the moment we can't see anything since we don't have acess to the image or the associated HTML in a demo that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Also as well as the HTML, it would be nice to use the original image, or at least know the dimensions. You can upload the image in your question, copy the link generated, and replace the local url's in `background`.

Comment: @jaunt Ive added all my code and Added the image Dimensions

Comment: @Paulie_D Added The code for a demonstration

Comment: Are you sure your image dimensions are 150x300, and not 300x150 or 1500x300? Because less width than height seems very odd when looking at your screenshot.

Comment: Sorry yes My height is 150 and a width of 300

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to drop the background on `body` and drop the `background-size` on `html`.
But this also requires you to change `no-repeat` to `repeat`, which will cause the page to be tiled with that image:

```css
html { 
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/150/300/) repeat center center fixed;
}
body {
    margin-top: 80px;
    font-family: 'passport', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        Test
    </body>
</html>
```

If you only want to repeat the image vertically, use `repeat-y` instead and set `background-size: 100% auto;`:

```css
html { 
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/150/300/) repeat-y center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
    -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
    -o-background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
body {
    margin-top: 80px;
    font-family: 'passport', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        Test
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not work, As you can see in the image below there is still no background behind the image which is what i need...https://i.gyazo.com/dc3d96cbab3e1c26757d58b30db51b39.jpg

Comment: @TomTucka Then either your `html` tag has a `margin-top`, or one of `section, #banner, .banner, .container, .row, .col-lg-12` (or any combination of those) has a white background set. You should be able to see where that's coming from, using your browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

@siguza said it could have been a background colour being set, On inspecting the element more I found it was being set in bootstrap.min.css which i never thought of...

Fixed by doing this

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px; 
    font-family: 'passport', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Thanks Again to Siguza